# What would be an english translation for "手中法訣"?

Tags: translation

By "手中法訣", I mean where their hands are rapidly moving in certain patterns in a special movement, but I don't know what's it called (if there's a name for it) nor how to say it english.

Comment: Like in the ones they used in Naruto? I never read the English version. But I think it should count as a type of maneuver.

Comment: Find one on wiki. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hand_Seals. So maybe "hand seals" is what your looking for?

Comment: Or is it "mudras", which is basically the same as "hand seals"?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are saying doesn't even exists in Chinese. 
Chinese magic emphasis ritual and 心法口诀. It never specifically mention any gesture. Let alone a combination of multiple gestures.
So your translation is determined by what magic system you use.
If your system is based on naruto. I think you already got the answer.
If your system is based on western magic. The I think "spell" is the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Over here, I'm taking an educated guess here but I think you may be focussing on Chinese Taoism/Taoists or something that focusses on "fairy/divine/immortal" (仙) where there is an element of magic/Taoist spells being involved that are composed of rituals, symbols and hand movements.

A less literal translation would be "invocation" as in the invocation of a spell or magic.